# How to get only one answer from if loop

Tags: java

I want to figure out which one of two people is older or younger by comparing their birthday. If their birthdays are different, it gives 1 correct answer, but when their birthdays are same, it gives me 3 answers(shown below), which is not my intention.

```
Person A is younger 
Person A is younger
Person A is younger
```

How to get only one answer `They are same` ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hghfg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner A= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Person A Enter Year");
        int B= A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Month");
        int C= A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Day");
        int Z= A.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Person B Enter Year");
        int D= A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Month");
        int E= A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Day");
        int F= A.nextInt();


        if( B> D){
            System.out.println("Person A is older");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Person A is younger");
        }

        if(B==D){
            if (C>E){
            System.out.println("Person A is older");}   
            else {
                System.out.println("Person A is younger");
                    }   
            }
        if (B==D || C==E){
            if (Z>F){
                System.out.println("Person A is older");}   
            else {
                System.out.println("Person A is younger");
            }
            if (B==D || C==E || Z==F){
                System.out.println("They are same");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if` is a *conditional* statement. It is not a *loop* statement. `for` and `while` are loop statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner A = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Person A Enter Year");
        int B = A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Month");
        int C = A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Day");
        int Z = A.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Person B Enter Year");
        int D = A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Month");
        int E = A.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Day");
        int F = A.nextInt();

        if (B < D) {
            System.out.println("Person A is older");
        } else if (B == D) {
            if (C < E) {
                System.out.println("Person A is older");
            } else if (B == D && C == E) {
                if (Z < F) {
                    System.out.println("Person A is older");
                } else if(B == D && C == E && Z == F) {
                    System.out.println("They are same");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Person A is younger");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Person A is younger");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Person A is younger");
        }
```

Try this. It will work, you should construct a proper nested-if in this kind of scenario. and I replace `||` condition to `&&` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of an if-loop and I don't see a loop.  If B < D or B == D, your first else clause always prints "Person A is younger" which is wrong, and is likely why you're getting multiple outputs.

Try this to start

```
if( B> D) {
    System.out.println("Person A is older");
} else if(B < D) {
    System.out.println("Person B is older");
} else {
    /* same year; do same pattern for month etc. */    
}
```

Comment: This is a simple if-else ladder exercise but I'm leaving the answer in nudge form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is something called an if else statement in java. I will demonstrate.

```
public class IfelseExample{
    int B, D;
    if(B==D)
        System.out.println("A sentence");
    else if(B>D)
        System.out.println("A different sentence");
    else
        System.out.println("Another different sentence");
}
```

What this code does is if B equals D, it outputs "A sentence", if B is greater than D, it outputs "A different sentence", and if neither is true it outputs "Another different sentence" I hope this helps!